# Can exceptions be raised/handled twice in a Python script (2.7.8)

Tags: python-2.7, exception

So I'm developing a program, for fun, that tells me how many times I have played a specific game at the same time as another person. There are three separate directories that the chat logs (that I'm pulling usernames from) can be found. I'm making the program diverse enough to work on other people's machines, which means they must manually input the directory for all 3 areas. Here's where my problem comes in: what happens if OSError is raised (and handled) twice?

At the current moment, when I test the program, I input an invalid path for the first of the 3 and the program prints a message telling me it's invalid (thus OSError has been handled); however, when I do the same for the 2nd of 3 paths, the message is not printed. I'm not sure why, though. Actually I'm not sure if I tested inputting two invalid paths in a row for the 1st of the 3 paths to see if it prints the message each time, but I think I tested that and it did. Is there any way I can ensure that message is always printed, for all 3 options, regardless of how many times it's been raised already?

EDIT: Just realised I got rid of the "OSError" part of my except statements (but I don't think that's *too* important to this question?), and forgot to mention, in case it's useful, that I'm on a Windows 7 PC

My code (the useful parts):

```
while True:
    try:
        SteamDirec = raw_input("Please enter the directory for steam KAG logs (ends in \Logs).\nEnter 'none' if you do not have steam KAG: ")
        if SteamDirec.lower() == 'none':
            break
        else:
            #SteamKAG(SteamDirec) commented out, not useful here
            break
    except:
        print "\nInvalid directory. Ensure the directory is correct and try again.\n"

while True:
    try:
        NonSteamDirec = raw_input("\nPlease enter the directory for non-steam KAG (release) logs (ends in \Logs).\nEnter 'none' if you do not have non-steam KAG (release): ")
        if NonSteamDirec.lower() == 'none':
            break
        else:
            #NonSteamKAG(NonSteamDirec) commented out, not useful here
            break
    except:
        print "\nInvalid directory. Ensure the directory is correct and try again.\n"

while True:
    try:
        ClassicDirec = raw_input("\nPlease enter the directory for Classic KAG logs (ends in \Logs).\nEnter 'none' if you do not have Classic KAG: ")
        if ClassicDirec.lower() == 'none':
            break
        else:
            #ClassicKAG(ClassicDirec) commented out, not useful here
            break
    except:
        print "\nInvalid directory. Ensure the directory is correct and try again.\n"
```

Comment: The exception is handled in the `except` clause, and you can re-raise it using `raise`, but once it's reached an `except` clause that handles it, unless you exit the block with a `raise` the exception is considered handled and gone, and so would not be handled by later `except` clauses. In addition, an exception is only handled by a containing `try`...`except` clause, if you want to capture it in later clauses, the entire earlier `try` will need to be contained within it.

Comment: Thanks, I rearranged some stuff and it works correctly now. Good to know a bit more of the minutiae of the `try` and `except` statements. Thanks again, @Petesh